# Cannot correctly iterate IFeatureCursor (calling ArcObjects from Python)

Tags: python, arcobjects, arcgis-10.3

I have started recently using some of the ArcObjects inside my Python modules. Having all the useful posts and insights shared by @matt wilkie et al, I was able to get started pretty quickly (installing the comtypes with pip and downloading the 10.2 snippet from Pierssen and changing "10.2" to "10.3" everywhere).

I am trying to iterate `IFeatureCursor` and get all the features inside a feature class. However, I am getting back only the latest feature (with the highest ObjectID value).

There are 6 features in the feature class hence `xrange(6)` to keep it simple.

```
from comtypes.client import GetModule, CreateObject
from snippets102 import GetStandaloneModules, InitStandalone

# First time through, need to import the “StandaloneModules”. Can comment out later.
#GetStandaloneModules()
InitStandalone()

def iterate_features():

    # Get the GDB module
    esriGeodatabase = GetModule(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\com\esriGeoDatabase.olb")
    esriDataSourcesGDB = GetModule(r"C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\com\esriDataSourcesGDB.olb")

    # Create a file geodatabase pointer
    file_gdb_pointer = CreateObject(progid=esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory,
                                    interface=esriGeodatabase.IWorkspaceFactory)

    file_gdb = file_gdb_pointer.OpenFromFile(r"C:\GIS\arcobjects\MyData.gdb",hWnd=0)

    #access contents inside gdb
    feature_workspace = file_gdb.QueryInterface(esriGeodatabase.IFeatureWorkspace)

    in_fc = feature_workspace.OpenFeatureClass("Warehouses")

    def enum_features(in_fc):
        """returns pointers to IFeature objects inside Feature Class"""
        cur = in_fc.Search(None,True)
        for i in xrange(6):
            feature_obj = yield cur.NextFeature()

    feats = [feat for feat in enum_features(in_fc)]
    print [f.OID for f in feats]

iterate_features()
```

The line `print [f.OID for f in feats]` returns `[6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6]`.

What am I doing wrong? The same logic with generator/yield (`def enum_features()`) works fine when iterating feature classes inside the feature dataset.

the `feats_OIDs = [feat.OID for feat in enum_features(in_fc)]` will give correct results, `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]`, without me making any modifications to the code. The problem seems to be in that when I create a list of features `[feat for feat in enum_features(in_fc)]`, they all refer to the same feature (because when I explore each of them later, each of them have the same OID).

Comment: Does it work if you interactively step through it? I'm also not sure how yielding during assignment works, you may want to separate it out (ie. `feature_obj = cur.NextFeature()` then `yield feature_obj`).

Comment: @Evil Genius I agree, I think that is where the problem is.  I was able to get this to work by just yielding the NextFeature.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out with the yield statement, I've updated my answer with more details on what's wrong with the features list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think a better approach might be to get the count first using the `FeatureCount()` method of the `IFeatureClass` Interface.  This worked for me:

```
import arcobjects # my copy of snippets
from comtypes.client import CreateObject
import os

pars = r'C:\TEMP\frontage_test.gdb\parcels'
fc = arcobjects.OpenFeatureClass(*os.path.split(pars))

def enum_features(fc):
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase
    qf = CreateObject(progid=esriGeoDatabase.QueryFilter, interface=esriGeoDatabase.IQueryFilter) #can use NewObj here too if you have it in your snippets
    count = fc.FeatureCount(qf)
    cur = fc.Search(qf, True)
    for i in xrange(count):
        yield cur.NextFeature()


for ft in enum_features(fc):
    print ft.OID
```

And from my `arcobjects` module, this is my OpenFeatureClass() function:

```
def OpenFeatureClass(sFileGDB, sFCName):
    InitStandalone()
    import comtypes.gen.esriGeoDatabase as esriGeoDatabase
    import comtypes.gen.esriDataSourcesGDB as esriDataSourcesGDB
    pWSF = NewObj(esriDataSourcesGDB.FileGDBWorkspaceFactory, \
                  esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspaceFactory2)
    pWS = pWSF.OpenFromFile(sFileGDB, 0)
    pFWS = CType(pWS, esriGeoDatabase.IFeatureWorkspace)

    # determine if FC exists before attempting to open
    # http://edndoc.esri.com/arcobjects/9.2/ComponentHelp/esriGeoDatabase/IWorkspace2_NameExists.htm
    #   5 = feature class datatype
    pWS2 = CType(pWS, esriGeoDatabase.IWorkspace2)
    if pWS2.NameExists(5, sFCName):
        pFC = pFWS.OpenFeatureClass(sFCName)
    else:
        pFC = None
        print '** %s not found' % sFCName

    return pFC
```

EDIT

@Alex Tereshenkov raised the question of how to get this into a list of pointers to `IFeature` objects, and this can be done with a list comprehension.  So the answer is yes.

```
>>> features = [ft for ft in enum_features(fc)]
>>> features[:5] # lots of features, so lets just show the first few
[<POINTER(IFeature) ptr=0x2b2d930 at 2c13440>, <POINTER(IFeature) ptr=0x2b2d930 at 2c13490>, <POINTER(IFeature) ptr=0x2b2d930 at 32f5210>, <POINTER(IFeature) ptr=0x2b2d930 at 32f5260>, <POINTER(IFeature) ptr=0x2b2d930 at 32f52b0>]
>>>
```

EDIT 2:

I found the problem.  We do not actually want to recycle the rows.  Once I changed that to false, we can get out each `IFeature` into a list.

`cur = fc.Search(None, False) #do not recycle this IFeature object!`

So now when you do this you should get an object for each row:

```
features = [ft for ft in enum_features(fc)]
print [ft.OID for ft in features[:5]]
```

This is laid out in the [help docs](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/arcobjects-net/componenthelp/index.html#/Search_Method/0025000002t9000000/):

> The recycling parameter controls row object allocation behavior.
>   Recycling cursors rehydrate a single feature object on each fetch and
>   can be used to optimize read-only access, for example, when drawing.
>   It is illegal to maintain a reference on a feature object returned by
>   a recycling cursor across multiple calls to NextFeature on the cursor.
>   Features returned by a recycling cursor should not be modified.
>   Non-recycling cursors return a separate feature object on each fetch.
>   The features returned by a non-recycling cursor may be modified and
>   stored with polymorphic behavior.
>
> The Geodatabase guarantees "unique instance semantics" on
>   non-recycling feature objects fetched during an edit session. In other
>   words, if the feature retrieved by a search cursor has already been
>   instantiated and is being referenced by the calling application, then
>   a reference to the existing feature object is returned.
>
> Non-recycling feature cursors returned from the Search method *MUST*
>   be used when copying features from the cursor into an insert cursor of
>   another class.  This is because a recycling cursor reuses the same
>   geometry and under some circumstances all of the features inserted
>   into the insert cursor may have the same geometry.  Using a
>   non-recycling cursor ensures that each geometry is unique.

Comment: Thanks for posting the code! Are you able to create a list of `POINTER(IFeature)` objects each of which will represent a feature in a feature class? Please see my updated question, would love to see if your features you create in a list would refer to actually different features with different OIDs.

Comment: No problem!  And yes, you can create a list of pointers to `IFeature` objects with the list comprehension as you had it set up.  See my edit.

Comment: Nevermind, that didn't work...I am having the same issue as you where I have the same OID.  I'll take another look after lunch.  The iterator seems to be acting weird.

Comment: Yeah, regardless the way used to construct a list of features (`for` loop with `list.append` or a list comprehension, I a list of the same feature). Would love to see what you could found.

Comment: I found the problem!  The problem was we were re-hydrating the row object by recycling it and using the same piece of memory for the row (`IFeature`) pointers.  Once you disable recycling, you can get an object for each row.  See my edit 2.

Comment: Works fine for me now. Thanks a lot, mate. Now I can sleep peacefully :D

Comment: Haha no problem!  And I know what you mean!  That was driving me crazy too; I couldn't figure out why I kept getting the same row object back.  I edited my "edit 2" again to add the relevant documentation that spells it out.

Comment: Terrific! Quite impressive how far you can go with ArcObjects from Python without writing any C# code (not fun after spending most of the time in Python imho). Mark Cederholm, who wrote the snippets102 module, is so incredibly smart (comtypes is hard to learn!), without him I guess we wouldn't be doing what we can do ;)

Comment: Indeed, that was genius of him.  And I agree, I am much more productive with ArcObjects in Python than C#, though I have seen some funky behavior, but most of the time things seem to work.  I have added quite a few things to extend the Snippets module (my `arcobjects` module).  It may be time to push it to my [GitHub page](https://github.com/Bolton-and-Menk-GIS).  Good luck with the ArcObjects stuff, it can be a bit daunting at times as the SDK is so huge  :)